# jQuery .one triggered by plugin event

Tags: jquery, popcornjs

Is there a way to trigger the removeClass using the jQ .one when it's wrapped in Popcorn .cue event?
Can this be done without rigging the internal Popcorn code itself?

```
popcornClip.cue( 41, function() {

  $('#ele').removeClass('someClass'); // I want this triggered only once

});
```

I know that it should only do it once as it is but I'm seeing a bug in how it's executed and I'm suspecting Popcorn cue may be at fault. So this is for debugging test

http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/media-methods/#cue

Comment: This question isn't explained very well.  So you want to run .removeClass() only once, on some event?  What event is that?

Comment: my apologies, Popcorn has cue() method which triggers whatever it has inside its function. The thing I want to test for is to see if that trigger occurs more than once which would cause the removeClass to be triggered several times. I'm trying to find a way to make sure removeClass happens only once when cue() is fired

Comment: It seems like .cue() should only be fired once, at a specific time in the movie.  If you want to see if it's getting fired more than once, try putting in a `console.log('cue fired!')` command in there.  But according to the API, the cue function should only be fired once, unless some other part of the script resets the time.

Comment: yes, somethings odd. thanks